# How to structure data: Solo Events (Lectures) and Group of Events (Conferences)

Tags: entries, query

I am working on my first craft project and am wondering how to create the following data structure:

I have a page with a large archive of solo-events (lectures, discussions etc). I think I will use a channel with categories for this.

In addition, there is a second content type: a conference. A conference is a group of solo-events. For example, several lectures and discussions.

The conference as a container has certain fields (picture, text) and the solo-events have other fields (speakers for example).

I wonder what is the best way in Craft to enable this form of container.

Example:

Solo-Events:

- Event 1 with Speaker a
- Event 2 with Speaker b

…

Conferences:

- Conference A

-- Event A1 with Speaker c

-- Event A2 with Speaker d

- Conference B

-- Event B1 with Speaker e

-- Event B2 with Speaker f

…

In the Frontend I would like to have:

Speakers-Archive:
I think this will be the easy one. For the speaker I would like to work with a channel and link them to the events.

Solo-Events and Conference-Archive:

A list with all solo-events and all conferences but without the sub-events.
So, this list should contain: Event 1, Event 2, Conference A, Conference B (A1, A2, B1, B2 should be excluded)

I am wondering how to deal with this idea of grouping the events to conferences:

I was thinking:

1. Two channels, events and conferences.

   All events (solo and conference-related) are in one channel. For a conference (second channel) I can select the events which I want to include. For the archive list I need to exclude all the solo-events that are part of conferences.
   This may not be optimal in terms of performance and user experience in the backend
2. Structure for Confernces and a Channel for Solo-Events

   The conferences are the parent elements, the solo events are the child elements.
   But how can I create different fields for the parents and children?
3. Structure with Entry Types:

   I wonder if i can work with entry type here as well.
   But But how can I bring the Entry Type together with the Hierarchy? So that Parent is always a conference and a children is an Event?
4. Matrix Field:

   The Conferences has a matrix field to store the individual events. But I dont like this approach because I think it would be hard to get all the speaker from a conferences matrix field and combine them with the speaker from the solo-events to get one list with all speaker
5. Categories.

   all events are stored in one channel and I create a Categorie for the Conferences.
   It feels kind of wrong-headed because the Conference (in my understanding) is the parent of the event rather than the category.

What do you think?

At the moment I am trying the second approach:

```
{# get all conferences (parents) (level =1 )  from a structure and merge with all solo-events from a channel#}

{% set entriesConferences = craft.entries.section('conferences').level(1).ids() %}
{% set entriesEvents = craft.entries.section(['events']).ids() %}

{# Combine those IDs #}
{% set entryIdsCombined = entriesConferences | merge(entriesEvents) %}

{# Get all entries (so, no IDs this time), using your IDs, order by date#}
{% set allEntries = craft.entries.id(entryIdsCombined).order('datumUhrzeit desc') %}
```

Is there a better (in terms of performance, scalability and user experience in the backend) way to archive this?

I asked this question Oli from the craft team and he gave me an answer that he will hopefully add here as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My approach:

- Create one channel for events with different entry types (solo-events, conference-events)
- Create one channel for conferences
- Re-use the date fields in both channels
- That way you can fetch and order events by the re-used date fields from both channels limiting to the entry types of solo-events and conferences with one query. That makes listings, filtering and paging easy.
- Conference-events can be eager-loaded with the query as well
- The entry type for conference-events has a mandatory entry field for the conference
- In the control panel you can show the related conference by adding the field as a column in the overview
- Speakers is another channel or structure being linked from within the conference-events

Why I would not use:

- Matrix: can be easily queried but can not eager load the entry it belongs to
- Category: feels wrong to always add categories for new conferences
- Structures for events: Structure are not 100% user friendly when adding new entries, as they always need to be sorted manually (though there are some improvements in 3.7 coming up)

Comment: Thank you very much! I am testing your approach at the moment and I have a question about it: Is it possible to filter the entries in the backend by its entry type? At the moment i have one channel with all events (solo and conference-related), each has an entry type like you wrote. Now I will have a very long list of entries in the backend. How to just get the entries of one type?

Comment: Or is it maybe better to work with two channels instead of one channel with two entry types?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to filter by entrytype. in this case, 2 channels are better.

Comment: thanks for your quick help!